# Days passed from the date entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I'm trying to work out a formula.
In `A1` I have any date. In `B1` I have any date. In `C3` I want it to return a value, which is the first part. The second is `A1` has a date `B1` is blank (no date). In `C1` I want the amount of days that has passed from the date entered in `A1` to today's date.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Excel stores dates in a numerical value. What formulas have you tried? This is well documented topic.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set:
`=TODAY()-A1`

Make sure that the number formatting for `A1` is set to "Date" and the number formatting for `C1` is set to `Number`

Comment: Thank you that gives me the answer to the second part, which is good.  what i ideally want is if a date is in both A1 and B2 then the formula moves on to till it finds a blank in B1 then does =TODAY() - A1.  hope that makes sense

Comment: @PsychoPenguin In that case you’ll have to create a new column D to not overwrite existing values in C. Type the following in C column: =IF(B1 =“”, TODAY()-A1, C1)

Comment: so =IF(ISBLANK(B1),TODAY()-A1,"-") works, but because of a formula in B1 it doesn't see it as a blank

Comment: @PsychoPenguin please update your question to reflect all the information we need to be able to help you (which includes any formulas in B1).